# Enable auto quotes for grave accents (`) in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've been working with SQL queries in Sublime Text recently and I find myself needing to wrap words with grave accents a lot.

For standard single and double quotes, sublime text allows you to select text and hit a quote key to wrap the selected text in the quote. For example, `hello world` becomes `"hello world"`

However, there is currently no way I can figure out how to perform the same action with grave accents (`). (`hello world` just gets overwritten with `)

Will I need to create a snippet to enable such an action, or is there an easy way to define what can wrap around selected text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Modify auto_match of quotes, adding an additional quoting character to Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341135/modify-auto-match-of-quotes-adding-an-additional-quoting-character-to-sublime-t/16346444#16346444). You can add a context entry for SQL if you would only like the behavior in SQL files.

Comment: Excellent. Nice find, thank you! I've voted this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mark progress on this, I easily created a snippet to perform this action:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
`$SELECTION$1`
]]></content>
<scope>source.sql</scope>
</snippet>
```

And added a key binding in my user preferences:

```
{
    "keys": ["`"], 
    "command": "insert_snippet", 
    "args": {"name": "Packages/User/Grave Accent.sublime-snippet"} 
}
```

In this case, my saved snippet was called "Grave Accent.sublime-snippet".

The issues in this case is that using a grave accent immediately after still creates two, when the other auto quoters simply add one.